# Unable to focus and give input to widgets in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

**Issue Resolved**: Q_OBJECT macro was necessary and proper signal slot declarations are also important for any other handles.

I am unable to focus on any input type widgets like `QTextEdit`,`QListWidget` etc.

**Note**: There are no compile time or runtime errors.

**Update**: `QSplitter` is working properly! I have a `QListWidget`, whose items I click but they are highlighted only when I make the next move with the splitter.

I have a `MainWindow` class derived from `QMainWindow` as declared in `main_window.h`:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
//some other members like menu and statusbar here
}
```

I have another class called `Stack` derived from `QWidget` defined in `stack.h`:

```
class Stack: public QWidget{
public:
    Stack(QWidget *parent=0);
//some other members
}
```

Constructor of `Stack` as in `stack.cpp` :

```
 Stack::Stack(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent){
        main = new QHBoxLayout;
        handle = new QSplitter;
        setupList();
        setupScreens();
        //above functions add the widgets to the handle splitter
        main->addWidget(handle);
        setLayout(main);
    }
```

If i open up this widget in a separate window from the `MainWindow` using `test->show()`, the things work as expected/as i want.
But doing this in the `MainWindow` constructor, renders it unclickable.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):QMainWindow(parent){
    Stack *test = new Stack(this);
    //test->show();
    setCentralWidget(test);
}
```

This is strange. Why am i not able to focus any widget that can take input e.g. `QTextEdit`,`QListWidget` or click any `QPushButton` widget?

Comment: Do your widgets appear as they are disabled, or do they just ignore your input?

Comment: not they just ignore input

Answer (score 0):

Please  compile following code, it was working..you are getting focus and edit on QTextEdit...

**stack.h**

```
#include <QWidget>
class Stack: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Stack(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Stack(void);
};
```

**stack.cpp**

```
   #include "Stack.h"
    #include<QTextEdit>
    #include<QHBoxLayout>

    Stack::Stack(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent){
           QHBoxLayout* main = new QHBoxLayout;
            QTextEdit *test = new QTextEdit;

            main->addWidget(test);

            //other things added to main layout
            setLayout(main);
        }
    Stack::~Stack(void)
    {
    }
```

**mainwindow1.h**

```
  #ifndef MAINWINDOW1_H
    #define MAINWINDOW1_H

    #include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
    //#include "ui_mainwindow1.h"

    class Mainwindow1 : public QMainWindow
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        Mainwindow1(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
        ~Mainwindow1();

    private:
        //Ui::Mainwindow1Class ui;
    };

    #endif // MAINWINDOW1_H
```

**mainwindow1.cpp**

```
  #include "mainwindow1.h"
    #include "Stack.h"
    #include <QTextEdit>

    Mainwindow1::Mainwindow1(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
        : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
    {
        Stack *test = new Stack;
        setCentralWidget(test); 
    }

    Mainwindow1::~Mainwindow1()
    {

    }
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow1.h"
#include <QtGui/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Mainwindow1 w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: as in the code above i have a `QTextEdit` widget in the Stack class added in its layout. That `QTextEdit` appears in the `MainWindow` but I am not able to click on it, set focus and write something. The same thing is happening to any widget which can take input like `QPushButton` or a `QListWidget`.

Comment: i added a `QSplitter` widget right now(along with some other objects), the cursor changes to the double arrowed one, but I am not able to adjust the widget sizes. I have set the `setFixedSize()` property in one widget. Removed that it worked! But now I have a `QListWidget`, clicking on items does not highlight them but the respective item is highlighted after I move the splitter.

Comment: You may set QWidget/QMainWidget property("setEnabled( false )") as false. Please chak that also, may be it is disabled, then no focus will be there..

Comment: Ok using `QSplitter` on the widgets is working, but still I am not able to give inputs to any widget that has it. like buttons or textareas

Comment: I think , Question need to update. Can you update the Question according to latest understanding ?

Comment: setting the `Q_OBJECT` macro gives an undefined reference to vtable error

Comment: @activatedGeek `setting the Q_OBJECT macro gives an undefined reference to vtable error` Run qmake and then rebuild your project.

Comment: alrite done that, but still clicking on the `QListWidget` items does not highlight immediately. Rather when I move the `QSplitter` the next time, my previously clicked item in the `QListWidget` gets highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

If some1 would find this looking for answer on how to set focus on input widget from UI in QT5 you can just use:

```
ui->plainTextEdit->setFocus();
```